# Recursive XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

Yet again a problematic task. I have a not really nice xml. For example the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Values>
<record name='svc_sig'>
<record name="sig_in">
    <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
        <record>
            <!-- Some irrelevant metadata information with value node name... -->
            <value name="field_name">docTest</value>
            <value name="field_type">record</value>
            <value name="field_dim">0</value>
            <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
                <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
                    <!-- Some irrelevant metadata information with value node name... -->
                    <value name="field_name">doc.name</value>
                    <value name="field_type">string</value>
                    <value name="field_dim">0</value>
                </record>
            </array>
        </record>
        <record>
            <value name="field_name">docListTest</value>
            <value name="field_type">record</value>
            <value name="field_dim">1</value>
            <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
                <record>
                    <value name="field_name">d0</value>
                    <value name="field_type">record</value>
                    <value name="field_dim">0</value>
                    <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
                        <record>
                            <value name="field_name">d0.name</value>
                            <value name="field_type">string</value>
                            <value name="field_dim">0</value>
                        </record>
                    </array>
                </record>
            </array>
        </record>
        <record>
            <value name="field_name">packages_should_work</value>
            <value name="field_type">recref</value>
            <value name="field_dim">0</value>
            <value name="rec_ref">data:packages</value>
        </record>
        <record>
            <value name="field_name">packages_list_should_work</value>
            <value name="field_type">recref</value>
            <value name="field_dim">1</value>
            <value name="rec_ref">data:packages</value>
        </record>
    </array>
</record>
</record>
</Values>
```

For simplicity I need to map this xml to a java class that's already given and I can'T change it. With that in mind I have to transform this xml into another with meaningful names. For example:

```
<sig_in>
   <record>
      <field_name>docTest</field_name>
      <field_type>record</field_type>
      <field_dim>0</field_dim>
   </record>
   <record>
      <field_name>docListTest</field_name>
      <field_type>record</field_type>
      <field_dim>1</field_dim>
   </record>
   <record>
      <field_name>packages_should_work</field_name>
      <field_type>recref</field_type>
      <field_dim>0</field_dim>
   </record>
   <record>
      <field_name>packages_list_should_work</field_name>
      <field_type>recref</field_type>
      <field_dim>1</field_dim>
   </record>
</sig_in>
```

So far I created something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/" name="service_signature">
        <sig_in>
            <xsl:for-each select="Values/record[@name='svc_sig']/record[@name='sig_in']/array[@name]/record">
                <record>
                    <field_name><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_name']/text()"/></field_name>
                    <field_type><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_type']/text()"/></field_type>
                    <field_dim><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_dim']/text()"/></field_dim>
                </record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </sig_in>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

While it works for the main elements will not work for the nested records. I could create a xsl:for-each and iterate over each item if the type is record, but that wouldn't solve much; because it can be any deep. I know I should use recursion i just can't image how could I do it in this particular case.

@Edit - Some correction to nested types:

```
<record>
  <field_name>docListTree</field_name>
  <field_type>record</field_type>
  <field_dim>1</field_dim>
  <record>
    <field_name>d0</field_name>
    <field_type>record</field_type>
    <field_dim>0</field_dim>
    <record>
      <field_name>d0.name</field_name>
      <field_type>string</field_type>
      <field_dim>0</field_dim>
    </record>
  </record>
</record>
```

So as you can see where the original type is nested I need the same in the resulting xml also. Or in a flat, I'd need some unique identifier in the parenting and child nodes so I know which contains which. On any way I should not loose the structure.

@Edit:
 - Really sorry I wanted to save space and I failed to show the complexity behind the walls. So every record contains value names nodes. Most of them only contains useless metadata information I don't need. Also there're two records, with @name {sig_in, sig_out}, from which I only need sig_in, with the field_name, field_type, field_dim informations, along with the nested records on the same way. I'll look over all recommended options and will try to modify them to match the needs tho.

Thanks for every help!
 - Joe

Comment: Only to have this clear. The output should contain any records form the input without considering any condition?

Comment: The structure should remain the same. Where a record is nested in another, it should be nested in the resulting xml too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="value[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates  />
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates  />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
  <field_name>docTest</field_name>
  <field_type>record</field_type>
  <field_dim>0</field_dim>
  <record>
    <field_name>doc.name</field_name>
    <field_type>string</field_type>
    <field_dim>0</field_dim>
  </record>
</record><record>
  <field_name>docListTest</field_name>
  <field_type>record</field_type>
  <field_dim>1</field_dim>
  <record>
    <field_name>d0</field_name>
    <field_type>record</field_type>
    <field_dim>0</field_dim>
    <record>
      <field_name>d0.name</field_name>
      <field_type>string</field_type>
      <field_dim>0</field_dim>
    </record>
  </record>
</record><record>
  <field_name>packages_should_work</field_name>
  <field_type>recref</field_type>
  <field_dim>0</field_dim>
  <rec_ref>data:packages</rec_ref>
</record><record>
  <field_name>packages_list_should_work</field_name>
  <field_type>recref</field_type>
  <field_dim>1</field_dim>
  <rec_ref>data:packages</rec_ref>
</record>
```

Update doe to more info in question:

You can easily put in some condition in the record or value templates.
This is what I understood: Only consider records which have a record with `@name` value is "sig_in".
Try this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="value[@name = 'field_name' or
                            @name = 'field_type' or
                            @name = 'field_dim']">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record[descendant-or-self::record[@name='sig_in'] or 
                  ancestor::record[@name='sig_in']]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates  />
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates  />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks promising but it fits to every record or value node, but I only need specific ones. This is indeed again my mistake I just tried to save a lot of space with not to paste the whole large xml. I'll update my original xml example.

Comment: @Joey: Did you look at the update. This only considers records with `@name='sig_in@name='sig_in`as parent or children (any deep).

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT is able to generate you posted result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/" name="service_signature">
    <sig_in>
      <xsl:for-each select="/record[@name='sig_in']/array[@name]/record">
        <record>
          <field_name><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_name']/text()"/></field_name>
          <field_type><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_type']/text()"/></field_type>
          <field_dim><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_dim']/text()"/></field_dim>
        </record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </sig_in>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, if you want to iterate over each and every record use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/" name="service_signature">
    <sig_in>
      <xsl:for-each select="//array[@name]/record">
        <record>
          <field_name><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_name']/text()"/></field_name>
          <field_type><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_type']/text()"/></field_type>
          <field_dim><xsl:value-of select="value[@name='field_dim']/text()"/></field_dim>
        </record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </sig_in>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a xslt that may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="record|value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@name">
                <xsl:element name="{@name}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>              
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>             
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your XML :

```
<record name="sig_in">
    <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
        <record>
            <value name="field_name">docTest</value>
            <value name="field_type">record</value>
            <value name="field_dim">0</value>
            <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
                <record javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
                    <value name="field_name">doc.name</value>
                    <value name="field_type">string</value>
                    <value name="field_dim">0</value>
                </record>
            </array>
        </record>
        <record>
            <value name="field_name">docListTest</value>
            <value name="field_type">record</value>
            <value name="field_dim">1</value>
            <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
                <record>
                    <value name="field_name">d0</value>
                    <value name="field_type">record</value>
                    <value name="field_dim">0</value>
                    <array depth="1" name="rec_fields" type="record">
                        <record>
                            <value name="field_name">d0.name</value>
                            <value name="field_type">string</value>
                            <value name="field_dim">0</value>
                        </record>
                    </array>
                </record>
            </array>
        </record>
        <record>
            <value name="field_name">packages_should_work</value>
            <value name="field_type">recref</value>
            <value name="field_dim">0</value>
            <value name="rec_ref">data:packages</value>
        </record>
        <record>
            <value name="field_name">packages_list_should_work</value>
            <value name="field_type">recref</value>
            <value name="field_dim">1</value>
            <value name="rec_ref">data:packages</value>
        </record>
    </array>
</record>
```

The result is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sig_in>
   <record>
      <field_name>docTest</field_name>
      <field_type>record</field_type>
      <field_dim>0</field_dim>
      <record>
         <field_name>doc.name</field_name>
         <field_type>string</field_type>
         <field_dim>0</field_dim>
      </record>
   </record>
   <record>
      <field_name>docListTest</field_name>
      <field_type>record</field_type>
      <field_dim>1</field_dim>
      <record>
         <field_name>d0</field_name>
         <field_type>record</field_type>
         <field_dim>0</field_dim>
         <record>
            <field_name>d0.name</field_name>
            <field_type>string</field_type>
            <field_dim>0</field_dim>
         </record>
      </record>
   </record>
   <record>
      <field_name>packages_should_work</field_name>
      <field_type>recref</field_type>
      <field_dim>0</field_dim>
      <rec_ref>data:packages</rec_ref>
   </record>
   <record>
      <field_name>packages_list_should_work</field_name>
      <field_type>recref</field_type>
      <field_dim>1</field_dim>
      <rec_ref>data:packages</rec_ref>
   </record>
</sig_in>
```